# screen freezes when using COM port with OPENCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to run motors using color detection through openCV and communicating via Bluetooth with my processor board.

```
// create serial port
myPort = new SerialPort();

// open serial port
myPort->openPort("COM6", 9600, "8n1");

int rightside = (frame_width/2) - 30;
int leftside = (frame_width/2) + 30;
if(posX>leftside)
        {
            printf("Go Left \n");
            SendRobotLeft();
        }
        else if(posX<rightside)
        {
            printf("Go Right \n");
            SendRobotRight();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Go Forward \n");
            SendRobotForward();
        }

void SendRobotRight()
{
  myPort->send("R", 1);
}
```

Similarly, I have made for rest of them. MY device Manager says COM5 and COM6 for Serial communication link over bluetooth. When i run this over COM5, it works but if I try to see the data being sent using Advanced Serial Monitor, it cant open COM5 because its being used by some other application.

It opens COM6 but when i try to run the program in COM6, my video windows do not show anything and appear GREY in color.

Any suggestions where I might be wrong?

Comment: not a c++ expert and don't have enough code, but ny guess is you're doing cv and serial communication in the same thread and the cv part might wait for the serial part to finish. try to run the serial part in a separate thread

Comment: I am running them in separate threads..i just mentioned the serial port coding portion.

Comment: how does the cv part tie to the serial part ? does the cv part wait for any data from serial at any point ?